# How to get google Advertising ID using Ionic 3 framework?

Tags: ionic-framework, google-advertising-id

I installed Google Analytics in my app.But i did't find any function to get the google Advertising ID.Please help me how to get Google Advertising ID in Ionic framework

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-get-google-advertisement-id-in-ionic/118591